# Internet access within AWS Glue job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Do Glue jobs have internet access?

Using this test job:

```
def have_internet():
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com", timeout=5)
    try:
        conn.request("HEAD", "/")
        conn.close()
        logger.warn('ok')
    except:
        conn.close()
        logger.warn('no ok')

have_internet()
```

It appears they do not...

Also, within a properly configured Glue dev endpoint, there is no internet access.

By properly configured, I mean within a public subnet (internet gateway), with S3 endpoint and internet gateway, and a working 'connection', and security groups.

But still no internet access...

I want internet access to be able to interrogate an on prem database, save to S3, and run another job to transform, and load to rds...

Can I use glue for the extract?

Comment: I experienced that accessing Big Query from glue dev endpoints fails with a timeout error, but it works fine from a normal glue job execution environments. That's a bit annoying and I don't know how these environments differ from one another.

Comment: Is your dev endpoint in a public subnet?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has resolved itself now, I suspect due to an update in Glue, or the associated infrastructure.

The connectivity issue was occuring from within the PySpark REPL, and not on the actual Dev Endpoint instance itself...

Anyway, for anyone else troubleshooting similar network connectivity issues with Glue, here is a list of possible causes:

Dev Endpoint needs to be in a 'public' subnet*
DHCP options need to have the default setting
Security groups, security groups, security groups
Subnet should be associated with an S3 Endpoint
...

Comment: facing the same issue, it was working yesterday, but having issues today...